# How to convert byte [] to Mat in java

Tags: java, android, c, android-studio, dji-sdk

I am working on DJI Mobile SDK in Android studio. I want to Apply Opencv filters on video live feed from the phantom drone camera. Video live feed is in byte [] videoBuffer as shown in the code.

```
mReceivedVideoDataCallBack = new VideoFeeder.VideoDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {
            if (mCodecManager != null) {
                mCodecManager.sendDataToDecoder(videoBuffer, size);
            }
        }
    };
```

One way I think is to first convert byte[] videoBuffer to Mat in java and then pass Mat address to extern C class.

Second is to pass byte[] videoBuffer to extern C as jbyteArray and then convert this jbyteArray to Mat in C.

I don't know the role of int size in the code.

I am facing problem in both. Any help will be appreciated. I am stuck on this shit for more than a month. :(

Answer (score 0):

videoBuffer may contains invalid bytes, so we need use 'size' to indicate the valid part, which means the valid bytes are starting from videoBuffer[0] and ending with last byte: videoBuffer[size-1]